# Groups-People Database Design - Need advise

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm developing an application in which users upload pictures to server and then send email to people they choose with a link that shows these pictures.

My question is about organizing the people in a database (I'm using MySQL).

I would like each user to have people tree like this:

- Family

  - Mom
  - Daddy
  - Jonathan
- Close Friends

  - David
  - Ronny
- Others

  - Julia
  - Piter
  - Alex
- Tanya (does not belong to any group)

I thought about the following organization in the database:

**Emails Table** (all users people emails)

[image]

**Groups Table** (all users groups)

[image]

**People Table** (all users people)

[image]

In the Emails Table, there will be no two identical emails. **name** in `Emails Table` is the name that the user gave to the person when he added his email (I call it default name). Each user may have different name for the same person. Hence, this is what **name** in `People Table` for. **name=NULL** in `People Table` means that the default name will appear in the people tree. **group_id=NULL** means that this person does not belong to any group.

Does all this seems reasonable ?

In addition, as you can see, there is some kind of emails sharing between the users. This means that if Julia changed David's email, all other users will also see this change (they will receive an email regarding this change). Do you think this can lead to problems ?

I'll appreciate your opinion !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oy. A given email can be associated with different "people"? I would argue the semantics of that are a quite ugly. I would rename the people table Contacts. I would also rename the 'name' field in the Emails table to DefaultName to indicate it's strictly a fallback.

Semantics aside (which are a big deal, if someone else has to use this db), you reference an owner as a foreign key using varchar(20). There's no indication of what it is referencing, I assume it is some sort of Owners table, with a username as the primary key. I would recommend an int surrogate key... What happens if a user wants to change their username?

Lastly, the stickler in me would change the 'groupless' contacts. I would make a default group for each contact, call it _Groupless, and assign 'groupless' contacts like Tanya to the _Groupless group. The application can sort out the details. I don't particularly like optional foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I accept most of what you say. However, I didn't say that "A given email can be associated with different people". **person_id** 1 and 5 in `People Table` do have the same **email_id** but it doesn't mean that these are different people. This is the same person, John, who's email is `johns_email@gmail.com`. misha calls him John (the default name) while jenya calls him Johnny. Does this makes sense, or I'm still missing something ? There is indeed another `Owners Table` and I will really change owner name to owner_id.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I think it would be better to make the name of the table Contacts.

Reason is that under your scenario, two different lines in the 'People' table can refer to the same real-life person. Normally you wouldn't think of different rows in a 'People' table as referring to the same person. A Contacts table on the other hand... if I have my mother in my email address book, and my sister does as well, that's two different contacts, but one person. Calling it people makes it look like my mother is two different people....

Comment: I agree regarding changing the name to Contacts. Thanks!